# After a recent update, Emails sent to me from the system have changed

Tags: server, 20.04

A few days ago I ran:

```
apt-get update -y
apt-get upgrade -y
```

Before that, emails I received from the system looked like this (output from curl):

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   357    0     0  100   357      0   1785 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1776
100   357    0     0  100   357      0    297  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   297
100   357    0     0  100   357      0    162  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--   162
100   357    0     0  100   357      0    111  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--   111
100   357    0     0  100   357      0     84  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:--    84
100   357    0     0  100   357      0     68  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--     0
```

and this (received via PHP):

```
PROBLEM
----------------
EAccessViolation in 
Access violation at address 00022088. Write of address 00C0F8FC.
  [???]      + 0
  [OurProgramName.exe]  System  TObject.Free + 0
  [OurProgramName.exe]  UnitDevice_Camera_Heimann   Finalization + 1
  [OurProgramName.exe]  System  FinalizeUnits + 0
  [OurProgramName.exe]  madExcept   InterceptFinalizeUnits + 0
  [OurProgramName.exe]  madExcept   InterceptHalt0FinalizeUnits + 0
  [OurProgramName.exe]  System  @Halt0 + 0
  [OurProgramName.exe]  OurProgramName  initialization + 54
  [KERNEL32.DLL]        BaseThreadInitThunk + 0
```

Now, emails I receive from the system look like this:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0 100   357    0     0  100   357      0    297  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   297 100   357    0     0  100   357      0    162  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--   162 100   357    0     0  100   357      0    111  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--   111 100   357    0     0  100   357      0     84  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:--    84 100   357    0     0  100   357      0     68  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--    68 100   357    0     0  100   357      0     57  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--     0 100   357    0     0  100   357      0     49  0:00:07  0:00:07 --:--:--     0 100   357    0     0  100   357      0     43  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:--     0 100   357    0     0  100   357      0     38  0:00:09  0:00:09 --:--:--     0 100   357    0     0  100   357      0     34  0:00:10  0:00:10 --:--:--     0 100   357    0     0  100   357      0     31  0:00:11  0:00:11 --:--:--     0 100   357    0     0  100   357      0     29  0:
```

and this

```
PROBLEM
----------------
EAccessViolation in TFormMain.SetFramePosition Access violation at address 00BD7510 in module 'OurProgramName.exe'. Read of address 00000000.   [OurProgramName.exe]    MainForm    TFormMain.SetFramePosition + 1   [OurProgramName.exe]   MainForm    TFormMain.FormResize + 16   [OurProgramName.exe]    Vcl.Controls    TControl.Resize + 0   [OurProgramName.exe]  Vcl.Controls    TWinControl.WMSize + 0   [OurProgramName.exe]   Vcl.Forms   TScrollingWinControl.WMSize + 0   [OurProgramName.exe]  Vcl.Controls    TControl.WndProc + 0   [OurProgramName.exe] Vcl.Controls    TWinControl.WndProc + 0   [OurProgramName.exe]  Vcl.Forms   TCustomForm.WndProc + 0   [user32.dll]      GetWindowLongW + 0   [user32.dll]       CallWindowProcW + 0   [OurProgramName.exe]  Vcl.Controls    TWinControl.DefaultHandler + 0   [OurProgramName.exe]   Vcl.Forms   TCustomForm.DefaultHandler + 0   [OurProgramName.exe]   Vcl.Controls    TWinControl.WMNCHitTest
  + 0   [OurProgramName.exe]    Vcl.Forms   TCustomForm.WMNCHitTest + 0   [OurProgramName.exe]  Vcl.Controls    TControl.WndProc + 0   [OurProgramName.exe] Vcl.Controls    TWinControl.WndProc + 0   [OurProgramName.exe]  Vcl.Controls    TWinControl.MainWndProc + 0   [OurProgramName.exe]  System.Classes  StdWndProc + 0   [user32.dll]       ClientToScreen + 0   [user32.dll]       IsWindowEnabled + 0   [OurProgramName.exe]  OurProgramName  initialization + 16   [KERNEL32.DLL]        BaseThreadInitThunk + 0
```

A lot of the newlines are completely missing.  What do I have to do to get the newlines back?

`lsb_release -a` gives me:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

`uname -a` gives me:

```
Linux companyname 5.4.0-170-generic #188-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 10 09:51:01 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Are the newlines gone or are they replaced by some other character?

Comment: They are gone not replaced.